# Property bind in zul view not happening when event registered by event listner is called and changes the property of view model

Tags: java, zk

I am new zk framework. In my zul file there is a notification count indicator, which is a property of view model and indicates the notification count. When I click on notification indicator it opens a toggle window containing notifications. Here I want to implement that when I read a notification , the count will be reduced by one.

> ```
>     <div class="notification_popup"
>          viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.zk.viewmodels.ViewAnnouncementViewModel')">
>         <a sclass="activity-dropdown" id="announcement_notification" iconSclass="z-icon-bell" popup="ann_notification,position=after_end,type=toggle" tooltiptext="Notifications">
>          <span class="num"><label value="@bind(vm.announcementCount)"/></span></a>
>         <popup id="ann_notification" class="header-top-dropdown notification-dropdown">
>             <vlayout id="vl" sclass="notify-popup">
>             </vlayout>
>         </popup>
>     </div>
> ```

```
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class ViewAnnouncementViewModel {

    private long announcementCount = 0; 
    @NotifyChange({".", "announcementCount"})
    public void setAnnouncementCount(long announcementCount) {
        this.announcementCount = announcementCount;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
    super.afterCompose(view);
    Selectors.wireComponents(view,this,false);
    Html h1 = new Html();
    h1.setContent("<h4>Notifications</h4>");
    vl.appendChild(h1);
    div = new Div();
    div.setId("announcementList");
        div = updateAnnouncement(div);  
        vl.appendChild(div);    
      }

    public Div updateAnnouncement(Div div){

        private Collection<AnnouncementResultDTO> searchResults = 
          announcementService.retrieveAnnouncement(instanceInfo);       
        announcementCount = searchResults.size();

        setAnnouncementCount(announcementCount);
    postNotifyChange(this,"announcementCount"); 

        for(final AnnouncementResultDTO pasrDTO:searchResults){
        A s1 = new A();
        Label l1 = new Label();         
        l1.setValue("Annoncements");            
        s1.appendChild(l1);
        div.appendChild(s1);
        s1.addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener() {
                 public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    announcementCount=announcementCount-1;
                    setAnnouncementCount(announcementCount);
                    postNotifyChange(this,"*");
                    Window window = (Window) Executions.getCurrent().createComponents("announcement_popup.zul",null,map);
                    window.doModal();
                }                
          });   
   }

}
```

But announcementCount is reducing when event fires but it is not reflected in view model. 
I think the problem is that if we debug and try to find the value 'this', it will contain object with two inner object , one is view model. Here we can understand that postnotify method receives not a view model, but a wrapper class which contain viewmodel as inner class. I dont know my assumption is true. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this . Use **postNotifyChange(ViewAnnouncementViewModel.this,"*");*** inside **onEvent()** method instead of **postNotifyChange(this,"")**;

```
s1.addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener() {
                 public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    announcementCount=announcementCount-1;
                    setAnnouncementCount(announcementCount);
                    postNotifyChange(ViewAnnouncementViewModel.this,"*");
                    Window window = (Window) Executions.getCurrent().createComponents("announcement_popup.zul",null,map);
                    window.doModal();
                }                
          });
```

Thanks https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/zk-in-action-mvvm-working-together-with.html

Comment: your solution is correct. If you check javadoc of `BindUtils`, the 3rd parameter is the bean reference. So if you need to notify `ViewAnnouncementViewModel. announcementCount`, you should pass `ViewAnnouncementViewModel` reference.

Comment: there are some strange code in your `ViewAnnouncementViewModel` e.g. `super.afterCompose(view);` . Because the class has no parent class, there should be no such method available to call.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have found the correct way to notify a ViewModel's property. But I recommend you not to mix MVVM and MVC pattern in the same scope. Because MVVM is a pattern that let ZK framework manipulate your components, but MVC is a pattern that you (app developers) manipulate components by yourselves by component API. Sometimes your manipulation might interfere ZK framework's MVVM working and produce an unexpected result. Such case is hard to debug for you. **One page in one pattern** is recommended.

For example, regarding the code snippets:

```
for(final AnnouncementResultDTO pasrDTO:searchResults){
    A s1 = new A();
    Label l1 = new Label(); 
    ....
```

If you need to create multiple component according to a collections, please use

```
<forEach items="@load(vm.searchResults)">
    <label value="Annoncements"
    ...
</forEach>
```

Please see [Shadow components](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/shadow_elements/shadow_elements.html) for details.